# The type initializer for 'MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConfiguration' threw an exception

Tags: c#, mysql, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

Hola buenas estoy intentando crear un aplicacion con xamarin en la que se conecte con una base de datos online(he probado a hacerlo en localhost tambien) y no funciona he seguido varios video tutoriales pero ninguna termina de salirme a pesar de que copie y pegue, asi que lo posteo aqui con el objetivo de conseguir una solucion, dejo aqui los enlaces que he visto para relaizar este proyecto
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oeUxMn5DlH0 |||||||| https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UA43p46H-Bg&list=LLTYzRPDu_9YO74reUZ0iWMw

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Quizás el problema es en la configuración de red, dale una revisada a este post: http://fredyfx.com/post/solucion-emulador-android-en-hyper-v-sin-conexi%C3%B3n-a-internet/

Comment: Intenta conectarte desde tu equipo usando MysqlWorkbench o la consola de linea de comandos, aplicando los mismos parametros de conexion. SI no conecta puede que la base de datos tenga restricciones para conectarse remotamente.

Answer (score 0):

el problema estaba en que con xmarin no se puede usar el driver de mysdql normal tienes que usar Xamarin.mysql